# How to convert a given string with special caracters into a string with correct accents?

Tags: r

Let's assume I have this given string `"Ã¢me enchantÃ©e"`. I would like to convert this string into `"âme enchantée"`.

How can I achieve doing that? I would like a general solution that could work for all accents.

Comment: Do you have some code you tried to get a solution with? It would help answering your question a lot.

Comment: @CodeF0x I will edit in a few minutes, when I front of laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of encoding, that you can solve as follows:

```
mystring <- "Ã¢me enchantÃ©e"
Encoding(mystring) <- "UTF-8"
```

and the result is:

```
mystring
"âme enchantée"
```

Comment: I had put `utf-8`in lowercase but now it works :-) . By the way, could you tell when it is better to use `UTF-8`or `latin1`?

Comment: I suggest you this post:
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-16/
Anyway it depends on what you are going to do with your data. I suggest you to check for a detailed answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/